# How to grep for a value after an = sign

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How do I specify a grep to look for all possible values

i.e., with a file like (the `9701` could be any value):

```
9701=1?? 
9701=10.Pp 
9701=1a 8a 
9701=3.a_tt 
9701=1/a -00
9701=Bg1998pps
```

I could try

```
egrep -Eo '9701=[A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]{1,50}' test.log
```

This only gives me Uppercase/lowercase & number values.  How do I include values with special characters in the grep request? i.e., with spaces, dots, hyphens, underscores etc.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific value on the right hand side, or do you just want to list all of the right sides?  If the latter, look at `cut`.  Are there values in the file that do not start with `9701` that you want to exclude from the search?

Comment: Best give an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include all other characters in your `grep` you could use this:

```
grep -Eo '9701=.{1,50}' test.log
```

The dot represents ANY character.

But that won't cut off the "9701=" part of each line. To achieve this you could use `cut`

```
cut -d "=" -f 2- test.log
```

Though this would stumble if the value would include `=` as well.

`sed` would fix this for you and is ultimately the better solution for your problem:

```
sed -r 's/^9701=(.*)$/\1/' test.log
```

or

```
sed 's/^9701=\(.*\)$/\1/' test.log
```

or even

```
sed 's/^9701=//' test.log
```

Comment: `sed -r` is for ssed or GNU sed, but is for ERE, for that PCRE `.*?`, you'd need `ssed -R`.

Comment: thanks @StéphaneChazelas. I found another problem with it: the edge case of an equal sign within the value would cut that specific line at the second equal sign. anyway: op has '9701=' in the example query so I guess this is a static string to catch.

Comment: `sed 's/^9701=//'` would be standard and simpler. The standard equivalent of yours would be `sed 's/^9701=\(.*\)/\1/'` (removed the `g` which makes little sense here).

Answer (score 4):

```
cut -d '=' -f 2-  data.in
```

This will treat each line as a number of `=`-delimited fields and return everything after the first field

Output:

```
1??
10.Pp
1a 8a
3.a_tt
1/a -00
Bg1998pps
```

If you need to be sure only to return things related to the initial part of the line (`9701` in your case):

```
grep '^9701=' data.in | cut -d '=' -f 2-
```

Alternatively, the whole thing with `awk`:

```
awk -F '=' '$1 == "9701" { sub(/^[^=]+=/,""); print }' data.in
```

This does a string comparison of the first `=`-delimited field to find the records we're interested in, then deletes the first field and the `=` delimiter and outputs whatever is left.

Answer (score 1):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -o1 '9701=(.*)'
```

Would print what's on the right of the left-most occurrence of `9701=` on a line (for those lines that contain 9701=).

With GNU `grep` built with a recent enough PCRE:

```
grep -Po '9701=\K.*'
```

Though that would not report an empty line for an input like `9701=` (that is where what's after `9701=` is the empty string).

Standardly, that would be a job for `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/9701=/\
/;s/.*\n//p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `grep` everything, that is not `=`:

```
# echo '9701=1?? 
9701=10.Pp 
9701=1a 8a 
9701=3.a_tt 
9701=1/a -00
9701=Bg1998pps' | egrep -o '9701=[^=]{1,50}'
9701=1?? 
9701=10.Pp 
9701=1a 8a 
9701=3.a_tt 
9701=1/a -00
9701=Bg1998pps
# echo '9701=Bg19=98pps' | egrep -o '9701=[^=]{1,50}'
9701=Bg19
## If you too need to include equal char
# echo '9701=Bg19= 98pps' | egrep -o '9701=.{1,50}'
9701=Bg19= 98pps
```

Comment: your output is exactly what you piped in your grep command.

Comment: Just added another line to show what `[^=]{1,50}` does.

Comment: indeed, but that is not what was asked for, or was it?

Comment: I think that not including `=` was implied, edited in case I got it wrong

Answer (score 0):

`grep` in `Perl-regex` mode with `lookbehind`:

```
grep -oP '=\K.+'
```